# How can I simulate multiple IF checks?

Tags: sql-server

I have this code:

```
IF (@TestStatusId = @MarkedByUser) 
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @NOOP1 BIT;
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN                    
      DECLARE @NOOP2 BIT;
   END
```

I would like to have three conditions. When @TestStatusId = @MarkedByUser, @TestStatusId = @MarkedByAdmin and a default when @TestStatusId is something else.

Is there a way that I can do this without multiple IF checks?

Here's what I want but syntax does not seem valid:

```
CASE @TestStatusId
WHEN @MarkedByAdmin THEN BEGIN DECLARE @NOOP1 BIT; END
WHEN @MarkedByUser THEN BEGIN DECLARE @NOOP2 BIT; END
ELSE DECLARE @NOOP3 BIT;
END
```

Comment: What do you want to happen in each case? Declare differente variables? Or make some variables have different values?

Comment: I would like to have code that runs to replace those DECLAREs Just put them in there to make the question short.

Comment: Most likely you'll have to use multiple (maybe nested) `IF`. `CASE` is a single expression that has a single result of a single type, you can't put this kind of code in `CASE`.

Comment: But what happens in the rest of your code? Which variable does it use? Or do you plan to repeat these `IF`s elsewhere, creating a dynamic SQL? Perhaps there is a better option if you detail the whole scenario.

Comment: @alan, this is a strange approach. What are you trying to accomplish? You can't check later for variable existence - code will fail and that's it.

Comment: @Alan, were you able to try the solutions provided here?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested IFs as suggested by @Vladimir

```
IF (@TestStatusId = 0) 
BEGIN
  -- CODE FOR NOOP1
  PRINT 0
END
ELSE IF (@TestStatusId = 1) 
BEGIN
  -- CODE FOR NOOP2
  PRINT 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- CODE FOR NOOP3
  PRINT 2
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I really dislike this approach; as you are declaring different variables, the rest of your code should have these `IF`s repeated to avoid using undeclared variables.

Due to the lack of more details of what you need to achieve, here is a very simple example of a way of doing what you say with dynamic SQL, without repeating code.

```
DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Variable NVARCHAR(10)

SELECT @Variable = CASE @TestStatusId WHEN @MarkedByAdmin THEN '@NOOP1' WHEN @MarkedByUser THEN '@NOOP2' ELSE '@NOOP3' END

SET @DynSQL = 'DECLARE ' + @Variable + ' BIT; SET ' + @Variable + ' = 1; SELECT ' + @Variable + ';'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynSQL
```

I hope that further explanation of your problem will allow me remove all this an suggest a better strategy.